# Firebase Datatabase - Query object inside another object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to get this book by its title, however this query is returning me all nodes without any filtering. Any suggestions on how to get into **volumeInfo** and filter by **title**?

```
mDatabaseReference.child(userId)
                .child(REF_FOLDERS)
                .child(REF_MY_BOOKS_FOLDER)
                .child(REF_BOOKS)
                .orderByChild("volumeInfo")
                .startAt(bookQuery,"title")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(buildValueEventListener(onDataSnapshotListener));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out how to do that. I have to use slash to access attributes in object.

Like this:

```
mDatabaseReference.child(userId)
                .child(REF_FOLDERS)
                .child(REF_MY_BOOKS_FOLDER)
                .child(REF_BOOKS)
                .orderByChild("volumeInfo/title") // here I get title from volumeInfo
                .equalTo(bookQuery)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(buildValueEventListener(onDataSnapshotListener));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase have the method "equalTo" that filter the value inside an attribute from the object, like "volumeInfo" is in your object.
If you do like this, will work:

```
mDatabaseReference.child(userId)
            .child(REF_FOLDERS)
            .child(REF_MY_BOOKS_FOLDER)
            .child(REF_BOOKS)
            .orderByChild("volumeInfo")
            .equalTo("titleSearched")
            .then (function (snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val()) // will print the title searched by volumeInfo
            })
```

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this, @Rodrigo. But no results are coming back now. Funny thing is, if I do that with id works perfectly. Looks like volumeInfo as an object cannot be filtered like this way. Also tried volumeInfo.title but firebase complains that no special characters can be used.